# Inserting maple or macaulay script in a paper

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing, latex

I see many wonderful papers where the authors include some script written in Maple, Macaulay or other software that are needed for their proof. How do you insert that in your tex file?

Comment: Dear @IMeasy, I am afraid this question is off-topic in this site. I am sure it would be welcome at tex.stackexchange.com, perhaps with a few details added.

Comment: ok, some time go mathematical writng was ok even here, but nevermind

Comment: That is true, @IMeasy. However, it is not so much the mathematical writing aspect which makes this question off-topic in my opinion. It is the fact that this question is actually about LaTeX. At this moment, the last question (other than this one) tagged 'latex' which has not been closed was asked on December 5, 2010.

Comment: The problem is that it's not a question on mathematical writing, but on LaTeX syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lot of languages, [lgrind](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lgrind) gives nice results, but it is no longer maintained and a bit long in the tooth. The [listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) package is a bit more modern.